# grouping a datetime column only by time

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2012, group-by

I have a column datedate format, with 15 min intervals and another column called datavalues with corresponding data. I want to roll up the data values to 1 hr. I am attaching a screen shot. [image]. So my new column should have the aggregated value of "DATA_VALUES" column. and the datetime column should represent just hours but not 15 min. Please help, I have tried cast() to convert to time but not able to proceed further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can truncate the date to the hour by using this formula:

```
DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, the-date-value), 0)
```

So the full query is:

```
SELECT
  DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, KEY_POINT_DTTM_15MIN), 0),
  SUM(DATA_VALUE)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY
  DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, KEY_POINT_DTTM_15MIN), 0)
```

Comment: Thank you sir, but my main requirement is to add those datavalues to 1 hr, so instead of 4 values, the select statement should display 2 cols. Data_values_aggregated which adds all the 4 values and then the datetime part should just display 2015-01-01 00:00:000, because for this hour the values have been added up into aggregated column

Comment: Ah, got it. See the updated answer. In the future I'd suggest including expected output in your question. You'll get a correct answer, and you'll get it a lot faster :)

Comment: Thank you so much sir.! you really saved me. :)